# Dark states, velocity selective coherent population trapping

Tags: resource-recommendations, laser, laser-interaction, cold-atoms

I am looking at papers that discusses existence of dark states, e.g. the classic "Laser cooling below the Doppler limit by polarization
gradients: simple theoretical models".

Is it true that center of mass motion is essential for darkness?

Is there a precise formula to express darkness condition in terms of the multiparticle wave function, i.e. with explicit nucleus and electrons degrees of freedom, that would be valid beyond weak field approximation?